# Display all fields regardless if total is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables:

- RequestPossibility with fields Id, RequestId, Text
- RequestCategory with fields Text, RequestId
- RequestOutcome with fields Id, RequestId
- Request with field RequestId

Here is my query that ONLY returns results when "Total" is not 0. I want to return all results for type "Text". Here is my query:

```
SELECT
                MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
                MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility,
                COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Request R
                JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON R.RequestId = RO.Id
                JOIN RequestPossibility RP ON RO.Id = RP.Id
                JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY RP.Id
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Comment: Hey, I had already tried that - and that wasn't even the fully correct answer anyway. So. Bite me.

Comment: There is no need for that kind of language. Your accepted answer used left join so my comment is correct after all.

Comment: I was playing around with right and left joins, and yes, I could have stated that in my initial question. However that was *not* the complete solution. I did indeed need to count a specific field as Allen May had stated in addition to using a combination of left and right joins as stated in my final post. That is the only way I could get this to work.

Comment: And, you didn't need to downvote me just for that either. Not everybody knows everything; that is why sites like this even exist.

Comment: **First**, Comments are not for answers, and since you didn't even mention left / right joins in your question, How did you expect anyone to know you've tried them? **Second** I didn't downvoted your question. **Third** Even if i did, that is still no excuse for your comment. **Foruth**. If I though this question was so undeserving, I would not have bothered to try and answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you count a specific field AND use LEFT JOIN you might resolve this.

```
 SELECT
            MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
            MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility,
            COUNT(R.RequestId) AS Total
FROM Request R
            LEFT JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON R.RequestId = RO.Id
            JOIN RequestPossibility RP ON RO.Id = RP.Id
            JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY RP.Id
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Comment: I tried that too, even tried various fields in the COUNT() function. I still can't get it to work. Thanks for all of your quick responses though. This seems like it should be a lot more simple than it is. Any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: @Allen May, I owe this to you. I was able to resolve this with a few tweaks to your Count() suggestion. I will mark you as an accepted answer. Thanks a million, I couldn't have come to this without you!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Let me if you get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

That's how SQL works. If there are no rows returned from the query (`COUNT(*) == 0`) you get no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
SELECT
                MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
                MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility,
                COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Request R
                LEFT JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON R.RequestId = RO.Id
                LEFT JOIN RequestPossibility RP ON RO.Id = RP.Id
                LEFT JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY RP.Id
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

**Edit #1:**

This was not specified in your question: "*I need ALL results from RequestPossibility.Text to return regardless of any of the other tables*".
Check the new query:

```
SELECT
                RP.Text AS TextPossibility,
                MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
                COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM RequestPossibility RP
                LEFT JOIN Request R ON R.RequestId = RP.RequestId
                LEFT JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON RP.RequestId = RO.Id
                LEFT JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY RP.Text
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Comment: Hmm.. LEFT JOIN didn't seem to work. I need ALL results from RequestPossibility.Text to return regardless of any of the other tables. I'm thinking the query just has to be rearranged somehow, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

When using left / right joins, the order of the tables makes a difference. 
Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(RC.Text) AS Text, 
MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility, 
COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM RequestPossibility RP 
LEFT JOIN Request R ON RP.id = R.RequestId
LEFT JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON R.RequestId = RO.Id 
LEFT JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId 
GROUP BY RP.Id 
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Comment: Why should it? RP is the alias of the first table.

Comment: Oh, you switched the order - sorry

Comment: But i am not so sure that is correct.  If the value is in Request but not RequestPossibility that changes the query.  To me the question is not clear.  This may be the proper answer.

Comment: Since the question lacks detials, That is a question only the op can answer, along with that strange change from requestId to Id on the last join... I guess we will have to wait for his answer

Answer (score 0):

You need left and you need to group by R.RequestId (the most left)

```
SELECT  R.RequestId,
        MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
        MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Request R
Left JOIN RequestOutcome RO 
  ON R.RequestId = RO.Id
left JOIN RequestPossibility RP 
  ON R.RequestId = RP.Id
left JOIN RequestCategory RC 
  ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY R.RequestId
ORDER BY 2, 3 ASC
```

It is strange that you flop to RequestId in the last join
That RequestId is not linked to R.RequestId

You want ALL results from RequestPossibility.Text then the base query is way off
Not clear to me what you really want

```
   SELECT  RP.Text AS TextPossibility
           MAX(RC.Text) AS Text,
           COUNT(*) AS Total
    RequestPossibility RP        
    left join Request R
      ON R.RequestId = RP.Id
    Left JOIN RequestOutcome RO 
      ON RP.Id = RO.Id
    left JOIN RequestCategory RC 
      ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
    GROUP BY RP.Text
    ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Comment: Trying to past my final answer.. sorry for the delay

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
                MAX(RC.Text) AS Text
,               MAX(RP.Text) AS TextPossibility
,               COUNT(R.RequestId) AS Total
FROM Request R
                LEFT JOIN RequestOutcome RO ON R.RequestId = RO.RequestId
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN RequestPossibility RP ON RO.Id = RP.Id
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN RequestCategory RC ON RP.RequestId = RC.RequestId
GROUP BY RP.Id
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```